# definir $scope dentro de callback em angular

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

Estou tentando definir uma variavel `$scope.plan_id` dentro de um `callback` utilizado no `$http`, e sempre quando verifico esta variável recebo `undefined`.

```
$http({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/api/pricings/get'
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.proposals.plans = [];
    response.data.forEach(function (plan) {
        $scope.proposals.plans.push({title: plan.description, id: plan.id});
    });
    $('.ui.search.plans').toggleClass('loading');
    $('.ui.search.plans').search({
        source: $scope.proposals.plans,
        onSelect: function (response) {
            $scope.plan_id = response.id; // definição de $scope.plan_id
        }
    });
}, function (response) {
        messageService.alertDanger('Ocorreu um erro ao exibir as propostas. Refaça o login e tente novamente.');
});
```

Este método esta dentro de uma função `$scope.show`, e estou tentando acessar o `$scope.plan_id` em outra função `$scope.save`.

Já tentei utilizar o `$apply()` mas a variavel continua sendo `undefined`.

Comment: O ideal seria você criar um service para salvar os dados, ou então um service com um metodo que retorna um $resource, para vc manipular o retorno no mesmo escopo do controller. (Não sei se falei besteira, mas é assim que faço na nossa app)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Quando se é feita uma requisição seja ela `$http` ou `$resource` no AngularJS na função de *callback* o escopo é diferente.

O que recomendo é que seja armazenado o escopo em uma variável antes da execução do `$http` ou do `$resource` e que essa variável seja utilizada dentro do *callback*